# Combine multiple columns into an array as one of the key in a results set

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having trouble placing data into its right structure. I have a result set data of:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'company_id' => 1,
    'company_abbrev' => 'amd',
    'description' => 'amd blah blah blah 1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'company_id' => 1,
    'company_abbrev' => 'amd',
    'description' => 'amd blah blah blah 2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'company_id' => 2,
    'company_abbrev' => 'int',
    'description' => 'int blah blah 1',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'company_id' => 2,
    'company_abbrev' => 'int',
    'description' => 'int blah blah 2',
  ),
```

I am trying to combine the description into its own array within each company in is single, unique entry:

```
array (
  'amd' => 
  array (
    'company_id' => 1,
    'job_description' => 
    array (
      0 => 'amd blah blah 1',
      1 => 'amd blah blah 2',
    ),
  ),
```

The loop that I am have it in is piling all the job descriptions in each different companies as it gets to the very last company. What am I doing wrong?

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($comp); $i++) {
            $companies[$comp[$i]['company_abbrev']] = $comp[$i];
            $array[] = $comp[$i]['description'];
            $companies[$comp[$i]['company_abbrev']]['job_description'] = $array;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to group the items with the same company id as one

Comment: @FestusYuma I want to make it unique to each company, whether by company id or the company abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($comp as $com) {
    if(!isset($companies[$com['company_abbrev']])) {
        $companies[$com['company_abbrev']] = array();
        $companies[$com['company_abbrev']]['company_id'] = $com['company_id'];
    }

    $companies[$com['company_abbrev']]['description'][] = $com['description'];
}
```

this loop groups it using the company abbreviation

Answer (score 0):

You can walk over the array like this below,

```
$res = [];
array_walk($arr, function (&$val, $key) use (&$res) {
    $res[$val['company_abbrev']]['company_id']        = $val['company_id']; // setting company id
    $res[$val['company_abbrev']]['job_description'][] = $val['description']; // AUTOMATIC mapping
});
print_r($res);
```

(**Output**)

```
Array
(
    [amd] => Array
        (
            [company_id] => 1
            [job_description] => Array
                (
                    [0] => amd blah blah blah 1
                    [1] => amd blah blah blah 2
                )

        )

    [int] => Array
        (
            [company_id] => 2
            [job_description] => Array
                (
                    [0] => int blah blah 1
                    [1] => int blah blah 2
                )

        )

)
```

([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b445020779ab8179816d4c352fdef1cbdffd1d23)).

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to check if subarrays are already declared (or to declare them as an empty array) before pushing data into them.

Use `extract()` to create simple variables instead of crowding the script with lots of square braces.

I added an `s` to the end of `job_description` because pluralization better represents the data.

Whenever using `extract()` be careful that keys being translated into variables will not interfere with other previously declared variable in the same scope.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pVhQk))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    extract($row);
    $result[$company_abbrev]['company_id'] = $company_id;
    $result[$company_abbrev]['job_descriptions'][] = $description;
}
var_export($result);
```